# mongodb find() with $in operator is sequential or parallel?

Tags: java, mongodb, concurrency

```
db.mycollection.find(
  {
    _id:
       {
          $in: [ "0001", "0002" ]
       } 
  }
);
```

What happens when I execute above query?

1. Single thread search for documents containing _ids 0001 and 0002, one after another.
2. Two threads starts in parallel, one for each _id.

My concern is that, if its already concurrent then should I use `Executors` for concurrent `find()` on each document in my java code for fast fetching ?

Answer (score 0):

Since calling `db.mycollection.find` will block until results are returned, you should not care if `find` is parallel or not. A reason for multiple threads (via  `Executors` for example) is when **you** want to run multiple `find`s is parallel.